# array_map() is only applying to the first element of the array

Tags: php, csv, array-map

I'm using the following call:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file), array($delimiter, '"', "\\"));
```

The first line is parsed into an array properly, but the second line remains as a string. The CSV delimiter is consistent in the test file (semicolon), and there are no strange characters that I can find. The file opens normally in Excel if I add `sep=;`. What issues could be causing this?

Comment: _the second line remains as a string..._ Does this also happen with other lines after the first line?

Comment: I'm unsure what you think `array($delimiter, '"', "\\")` is doing? Are you expecting it to become the remaining args for `str_getcsv`?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Yes, this happens with all lines after the first

Comment: @Jonnix That is the behavior described in the array_map() documentation, and it is the behavior that applies to the first line. Without that argument, the default delimiter would be a comma.

Comment: Do the docs say that? That's not what I'm reading, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think you may need to re-read the docs (the way they're written is admittedly confusing as hell). The first value of the first array, and the first value of the second array get passed as arg 1 and 2 to str_getcsv. So that's why the delimiter is working for that line. Then it sends the second value of the first array, and second value of the second array to str_getcsv. Well `"` isn't your delimiter, but that's what you're telling it.

Comment: God lord. Alright. If you want to post that comment as an answer I'll accept it, because that seems to be the solution.

Comment: Painful, I know. I read it the same way as you first time -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of how [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) works (the language in the docs is rather confusing).

Taking the given snippet:

`$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file), array($delimiter, '"', "\\"));`

This is functionally similar to doing the following:

```
str_getcsv('line one of $file', $delimiter);
str_getcsv('line two of $file', '"');
str_getcsv('line three of $file', "\\");
```

This is why the first line appears to work, as the delimiter is correct, but the subsequent ones do not as the second param is incorrect in context of the CSV.